# resizing lots of images

Tags: php, image

I am working on a website for a retirement home in PHP and I made a user interface that has to resize a lot of images at the same time to a 300/300px size.

The user uploades a lot of images in a 'temp' directory, the when he wishes to save them, every one of those images gets resized to above size and both images are then saved and/or moved to different directories, depending on their size.

Large images to 'thumbnail' directory, resized small images to 'small' directory.

My question is, would there be any performance hits or script fails or script timeouts in that situation? For example, 50 images, total 50MB (or 200MB for that matter), all get resized in a loop one by one, and then, all of them saved and/or moved to their desired directories.

I haven't done this beacuse I'm on a deadline and I can't spend time doing this then finding out it's a bad design decision.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Define "performance hit". What is acceptable? We can't give you an approximate amount of time that this would take because that refers on too many localized variables

Comment: Yes but there are also host restrictions on script timeouts, if I'm not mistaken. If the use uploads 200MB of images, will the application blow up? In a normal situation, i would do it but I'm on a tight deadline.

Comment: We don't know your host. You need to check with them if there is some hard upper limit on script timeouts that they enforce. I don't know why they would.

Comment: So, in your experience, resizing a lot of already saved images would not make a performance hit and blow up? Usually, i would test it myself, but I have to make a lot of code just to be able to test it in the actual code of the website for what i don't have the time.

Comment: Try putting incremental sleep()s in your script (2s, 5s, 10s, 20s) until it breaks to find the timeout - should be easy enough to test quickly.

Comment: Again, performance hit is relative here. We don't know how long it's going to take your server to process these images because we don't know all the factors involved. We also don't know what is acceptable in your opinion. If you are simply worried about the page timing out, then increase the page timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resizing 50 photos is likely too much processing to do while expecting the user to wait for it. In this case, I would recommend that your web app submit the work to a job queue and then immediately return to the user, with some sort of message that their photos will be processed soon. Then you have a continually running offline job that works on whatever is pending in the queue. This could be as simple as dropping the files in a directory and then running a shell script via cron, or could be something more elaborate like a [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) worker.

Comment: It's an administrative user interface designed only for the owner of the website so waiting is fine.

Comment: If making them wait is acceptable then you're at the mercy of your script timeout. You're going to need to find out what that is, and run some tests to see if a 50-image resize takes longer.